# Ruby error with non-required arguments on method

Tags: ruby

This is on Ruby 2.1.8.

I have the following method:

```
def self.notify(methods=[], user, message_key, notifiable_id=nil, notifiable_type=nil)
  # Do some stuff
end
```

When I try to use this method and pass in valid values, I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError:
: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'
...er, message_key, notifiable_id=nil, notifiable_type=nil)
...                               ^
: Can't assign to nil
...message_key, notifiable_id=nil, notifiable_type=nil)
...
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out why. If I remove the `=nil` from `notifiable_id` and `notifiable_type` in the method arguments, everything works fine.

And FWIW assigning `methods` to an empty array is not the issue. If I don't assign that or assign it to `nil` I get the same issue.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a default defined for the 'methods' argument but then no defaults for user or message_key. You cannot have any arguments without a default value after an argument with a default value.

Comment: Aaah, serious? I did not know this. (But now that I'm thinking about it, that makes total sense...)

Comment: This is inaccurate. Try this example: `def test(a=1, b); a + b; end`. If you call `test 4`, it'll return `5`. `test 2` will return `3`, etc.

Comment: @jeffdill2 You are correct, the situation is not as simple as I described. It appears that Ruby 1.9 changed to allow default values for parameters before parameters without defaults. The problematic situation appears to arise when providing default values for non-consecutive parameters.